# Redirect in express

Tags: json, reactjs, express, redirect

I am using express and I would like to redirect to another file since my server is not always up and running. I can not understand why I am receiving a HTML document when my file is JSON. It looks like it gets redirected, but the result is wrong. I can see that my page is redirected from the old URL to the new URL. So it looks like that part is working. But I am not receiving my local json-file in the response.

What I have in my server index.js file:

```
app.use('/my/original/url', (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(302, { location: '/mock/mockedresult.json' });
  res.end();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I need to make my mock folder available. I did so by adding this line of code above the code snippet in my question:

```
app.use('/mock', express.static(resolve(process.cwd(), 'server/mock')));
```